# Finding the point which minimizes the distance given a point in space and constraints?

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, computational-geometry, trigonometry, mathematical-optimization

I have a question regarding an algorithm:

We have a fixed point in 2D space let's call it S(x,y) and the length of two links joining (L1 and L2). These two links are connected at a common joint called E(x,y). And we have another point in the space which is end point of the L2 which we call F(x,y).

So we L1 have two end points S and E where as L2 has E and F.

When we are given a point P(x,y) in space. How can we find the coordinate of F(x,y) which is closest to P? I wanted to find the angle of  θ1 and  θ2 which takes the links L1 and L2 to that point?

[See this link to get the graphical representation of my problem](http://postimage.org/image/flgbcmbpx/)

---

See this pic http://postimage.org/image/qlekcv1qz/, where you will be able to see the real problem I have right now.

So I have formulated this as optimization problem. Where the Objective function is:

```
   * arg min |P-F|
```

with constraints θ1 and θ2 where θ1 ∈ [ O , π] and  θ2 ∈ [ O , π/2].

So we have,

```
   * xE = xS + L1  * Cosθ1  and yE = yS + L1 * Sinθ1
   * xF = xE + L2 * Cos (θ1 + θ2 )  and yF = yE + L2 * sin ( θ1 + θ2)
```

Here we have length of L1 = 105 and L2 = 113.7 and Point S is the origin i.e xS = O and yS = O.

Can you give a hint how code up my function or any optimization problem which gives me the values of θ1 and θ2, such that the distance between Point F and point P is minimized.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, your description is equivalent of having two rigid rods of length L1 and L2, with one end of L1 fixed at S, the other end connected to L2 by a flexible joint (at some undefined point E), and you want to get the other end of L2 (point F) as close to some point P as possible. If this is the case then:

```
 If |L1-L2| < |P-S| < |L1+L2| then F = P
 If |L1-L2| > |P-S| then F = S + (P-S)*|L1-L2|/|P-S|
 If |P-S| > |L1+L2| then F = S + (P-S)*|L1+L2|/|P-S|
```

Is that what you want?

See imnage
http://postimage.org/image/l1ktt0qtb/

If point P is closer to point S than the distance |L1-L2| (assuming they are unequal), then point F cannot 'reach' point P, even with the angle at E bent to 180 ndegrees. Then the closest you can get is somewhere on the the circle with radius |L1-L2| and centre S. In this case the best F is given by the vector with direction (P-S), and magnitude |L1-L2|, my case 2 above and Figure A below. Note that if L1=L2 this will never be the case.

If point P is further from point S than the distance |L1+L2|, then point F cannot 'reach' point P, even with the angle at E straightened to 0 degrees. Then the closest you can get is aomewhere on the the circle with radius |L1+L2| and centre S. In this case the best F is given by the vector with direction (P-S), and magnitude |L1+L2|, my case 3 above and Figure B below.

If point P is betwen the two limiting circles, then there will be two solutions (one as shown in Figure 3 below, and the other with L1 and L2 reflected in the mirror line formewd by the vector P-S. In this case the 'best' F is *equal* to point P.

If you want to know the angles Theta1 and Theta 2 then that is a different question (I see you have added that now).

Use the cosine rule for triangles with no right angle.

The rule is

```
 C = acos[(a^2 + b^2 - c^2)/(2ab)]
```

where a triangle has sides of length a,b, and c, and C is the angle between sides a and b. You are trying to produce a triangle with sides l1, l2, and d=|S-P|, which will be possible so as long as no two of the lengths are shorter (in sum) than the third one.

By substituting l1, l2, and d for a,b, anc c appropriately you will be able to solve for each of the internal angles, A, B, and C. Then you can use these angles A,B,C plus the angle between the vector P-S and horizontal (call that D perhaps?) to calculate your theta1 and theta2.

Comment: I think you miss understood my question. I have just added a graphical representation of my question to the original one. I hope it will be clear enough right now.

Comment: @atir See the changes I have made to clarify my answer

Comment: yeah i think you answered what I asked in the forum clearly. But I think i didn't clearly asked the difficulty I was having. See below what I really want to be solved. http://postimage.org/image/qlekcv1qz/